# how to get all details of a particular userid in a json file in python

Tags: python-3.x, analytics

i want to access the particular userid details

```
[
    {
        "userID": 998926445,
        "contentID": [
            [
                "5bbae768c1df412352000004"
            ],
            [
                "5ba8d4fac1df413dae0002cf"
            ],
            [
                "5ca61afced8f7d3a5f00102d"
            ],
            [
                "5b9c9cacc1df41453400003f"
            ],
            [
                "5c8a8044a58c4046b30030f2"
            ],
            [
                "5ba9070bc1df413dae0003c3"
            ],
            [
                "5bbb1087c1df4140a6000162"
            ],
            [
                "5c95142bed8f7d5ede004ef4"
            ],
            [
                "5ba905e5c1df413dae0003b9"
            ],
            [
                "5bb89799c1df41262300062a"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "userID": 998926445,
        "contentID": [
            [
                "5baa8ef5c1df41479a0004b8"
            ],
            [
                "5c8a8063a58c4046c8000e89"
            ],
            [
                "5bbc7a16c1df412a82000008"
            ],
            [
                "5bb8964ec1df41262300060c"
            ],
            [
                "5bbc4f92c1df4140a6000abe"
            ],
            [
                "5bbb0ecbc1df4140a60000fc"
            ],
            [
                "5ba90aa2c1df413dae000429"
            ],
            [
                "5bf2bb06c1df411238003054"
            ],
            [
                "5cb0c006ed8f7d6a1d00146a"
            ],
            [
                "5bbc9825c1df41384100024c"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "userID": 998926445,
        "contentID": [
            [
                "5bb8974cc1df412623000622"
            ],
            [
                "5b9c9cadc1df414534000047"
            ],
            [
                "5b8e5b32c1df412918000048"
            ],
            [
                "5b9c9cacc1df41453400003f"
            ],
            [
                "5bb8ac8ac1df4126230008a0"
            ],
            [
                "5b9fad7bc1df4145340000a7"
            ],
            [
                "5bbb1171c1df4140a600016c"
            ],
            [
                "5c8a8071a58c4046c8000e8d"
            ],
            [
                "5ba90dbac1df413dae00043d"
            ],
            [
                "5ba8f905c1df413dae000397"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Comment: The json is inside the list. Can you remove the outer list and try using the userid with key. It will give particular user details.

Comment: i removed the outer list and tried to get the details of a particular userid but due to multiple  key values of content id i am not able to get the result using the method get()

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this. You will get the list. then you can work on fixing it. Let us assume json_list is your original json list.

```
from collections import defaultdict 
dd = defaultdict(list)

for i in json_list:
    dd[i['userID']].append([j[0] for j in i['contentID']])

dd = dict(dd)
print(dd)
```

Your output will be something like this:

```
{998926445: [['5bbae768c1df412352000004', '5ba8d4fac1df413dae0002cf', '5ca61afced8f7d3a5f00102d', '5b9c9cacc1df41453400003f', '5c8a8044a58c4046b30030f2', '5ba9070bc1df413dae0003c3', '5bbb1087c1df4140a6000162', '5c95142bed8f7d5ede004ef4', '5ba905e5c1df413dae0003b9', '5bb89799c1df41262300062a'], ['5baa8ef5c1df41479a0004b8', '5c8a8063a58c4046c8000e89', '5bbc7a16c1df412a82000008', '5bb8964ec1df41262300060c', '5bbc4f92c1df4140a6000abe', '5bbb0ecbc1df4140a60000fc', '5ba90aa2c1df413dae000429', '5bf2bb06c1df411238003054', '5cb0c006ed8f7d6a1d00146a', '5bbc9825c1df41384100024c'], ['5bb8974cc1df412623000622', '5b9c9cadc1df414534000047', '5b8e5b32c1df412918000048', '5b9c9cacc1df41453400003f', '5bb8ac8ac1df4126230008a0', '5b9fad7bc1df4145340000a7', '5bbb1171c1df4140a600016c', '5c8a8071a58c4046c8000e8d', '5ba90dbac1df413dae00043d', '5ba8f905c1df413dae000397']]}
```